# Find last used element in object array

Tags: c++, arrays

I have an array of `Student` objects. I set the array length to 100, but it doesn't have 100 valid `Student` objects in it. I want to be able to iterate through the array and grab all the valid `Student` objects, then stop when I get to an array cell that doesn't have a Student object.

I have tried putting `NULL` into the array cell after the last Student, and then checking `if (queriedStudents[i])` as well as `if(queriedStudents[i] != NULL)`, but neither has worked for me.

What is the best way to find the end of the used part of my array?

```
Student *Welcome::queryStudents(int *queries) {
    int query = 0;
    Student *matchedStudents[100];
    int matchedPos = 0;
    while (queries[query] > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < numStudents; i++) {
            if (allStudents[i]->id == queries[query]) {
                matchedStudents[matchedPos] = allStudents[i];
                matchedPos++;
            }
        }

        query++;
    }
    matchedStudents[matchedPos] = NULL;

    return *matchedStudents;
}
```

And my code chunk trying to print out each `Student`'s values:

```
        int i = 0;
        while (i < 100) {
            if (queriedStudents[i]) {
                cout << "ID:\t" << queriedStudents[i]->id << endl;
                cout << "Name:\t" << queriedStudents[i]->name << endl;
                cout << "Addr.:\t" << queriedStudents[i]->address << endl;
                cout << "Phone:\t" << queriedStudents[i]->phone << endl;
            } else {
                i = 100;
            }
            i++;
        }
```

Comment: If possible, use `std::vector` instead of an array -- it'll keep track of the number of objects it contains.

Comment: If your array contains pointers then what you described using NULL would work as long as you initialized the array with NULL before you started adding pointers to it.  This would leave you having to handle the new/delete on each item manually though.  As Jerry said, vector is a good choice to avoid this and only store what you're actually using.  Another alternative if you can't use vector for whatever reason could be to add a `valid` member to your Student object that is default initialized to false and only set to true when real data is present in the object.

Comment: @RetiredNinja: Good comment, better answer.  Post it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got a bigger problem. You declare the array `matchedStudents` on the stack in the function `queryStudents`. When control passes out of that function, the array passes out of scope. If you're trying to use it later (by means of the pointer it returns, which was the first element of the array) then you're messing with deallocated memory, which will almost certainly lead to undefined behavior. It's as if you're visiting a house that has changed owners since you were last there; there's no telling what's changed, and if you wander around with your eyes closed you might get into trouble.

You can declare the array on the heap:

```
Student **Welcome::queryStudents(int *queries) {
  Student **matchedStudents = new *Student[100];
    ...
  return matchedStudents;
}
```

Or pass it in by reference:

```
void Welcome::queryStudents(int *queries, Student **&matchedStudents) {
    ...
}
```

Either way, you can then tackle the problem of how to indicate the end of valid pointers. Your method looks feasible, but bear in mind that as @JerryCoffin has pointed out, `std::vector` is available. Arrays are a pain, and the STL containers (such as `vector`) were made to take care of these grubby details for you. These days working with arrays serves almost no purpose except pedagogy; play with them until you understand the concepts, then use more advanced containers which are base on them.

Comment: That's pretty much exactly where I'm at; This is the first assignment of my class this semester, and my biggest problem is switching from Java and AS3 to C++. Once I get the concepts down, I'll move on.